# How to remove panels from Gutenberg in cleared way?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am looking for some of code which will help me delete panels from Gutenberg but specifically with the settings just for selected roles and not for every of them etc. I tried everything but problem is Gutenberg using panels and not metaboxes like Classic Editor before.

Is there someone, who knows how to turn off metaboxes in gutenberg for x user levels?

I tried https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box , but as I said, that will no work because Gutenberg.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know Gutenberg ignores remove_meta_box. You can remove a panel by doing the following:

In **PHP** register a script. Also register an empty block and add a JS file to it.

```
function hughie_register_files() {
    // script file
    wp_register_script(
        'hughie-admin-panels',
        plugins_url('/scripts/admin-panels.js', __FILE__),
        [ 'wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post' ]
    );
    // register block editor script
    register_block_type( 'hughie/admin-panels', array(
        'editor_script' => 'hughie-admin-panels'
    ) );
}
```

In the **JS** file add any of the following lines:

```
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'taxonomy-panel-category' ) ; // category
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'taxonomy-panel-TAXONOMY-NAME' ) ; // custom taxonomy
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'taxonomy-panel-post_tag' ); // tags
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'featured-image' ); // featured image
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'post-link' ); // permalink
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'page-attributes' ); // page attributes
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'post-excerpt' ); // Excerpt
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'discussion-panel' ); // Discussion
```

Your problem is you only want to include the file is the user has a certain capability.

All WP hooks can be found at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

By the time **init** is called the user should be defined and available to check

Comment: Init is a wordpress action hook. Just put the function on that hook

Comment: How do you check user role here?

Comment: @Shahriar check out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-specific-role